# the distance between a holomorphic function and $\overline{z}$ cannot be bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $g(z)$ is a complex function holomorphic on the unit disk. prove that for all $K<1$ there exists $z$ in the unit disk, such that: $|g(z)-\overline{z}|>K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose not. Then $|g(z)-\overline{z}|\leq K$ for all $z\in\mathbb D$. Consider $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb C,\ t\mapsto re^{it}$ for some $r\in(0,1)$. Then, using the Cauchy Integral Theorem,
\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma (g(z)-\overline z)dz=-\int_\gamma\overline z dz=-2\pi i r^2,
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_\gamma (g(z)-\overline z)dz\right|=2\pi r^2.
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_\gamma(g(z)-\overline z)dz\right|\leq\int_\gamma|g(z)-\overline z|dz\leq 2\pi r\cdot\sup_{z\in\gamma([0,2\pi])}|g(z)-\overline z|=2\pi r\cdot K,
\end{align*}
leading to a contradiction for any $r>K$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose that there exists a constant $K\in (0,1)$ such that  $ (*)|g(z)-\overline{z}|\leq K$ for all $z$ in the unit disk. Let $r\in (0,1)$. Compute first the integral of $g(z)-\overline{z}$ over the circle $C_r=\{z; |z|=r\}$, and then bound it using $(*)$.